# Создание проектов c# по шаблону. vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Я пытаюсь работать с C# из vscode а не полноценной средой vs по некоторым причинам. Создание консольного проекта доставляют некоторые сложности если использовать .NET Framework а не Core. В случаи с Core достаточно в консоли ввести:

`dotnet new console`

Можно ли поместить проект в директорию с портативной vscode и в нужный момент ее распаковывать в открытый каталог из самой программы, заранее указав имя нового проекта. Если это можно решить отдельным самописным расширением или чем либо то я готов на эти действия.

Буду благодарен за ваши идеи или опыт в этом плане!

Comment: Нагуглил [это](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cantonios.project-templates)

Comment: так как я ничего не нашел я принялся за написание собственного расширения =) и оно уже работает... а тут оказывается есть готовое решение... Спасибо большое за помощь) даже не знаю на чем теперь остановиться